# find and click create new account button from google

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, google-chrome, firefox

I'm trying to find and click this button to create a new google account with selenium in python.
But

```
 sleep(5)  # sleep 5 sec
 self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Konto erstellen')]")  # doesn't work
 self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]  #doesn't work/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div').click()
 self.driver.find_element_by_name('Konte erstellen').click()  #doesn't work[i][1]
```

nothing works for me. thanks for your help
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/flAK6.png
  link to bewsite: "https://accounts.google.com/signin/v2/identifier?flowName=GlifWebSignIn&flowEntry=ServiceLogin"

Comment: Can you Post HTML of that webpage?

Comment: [link](https://accounts.google.com/signin/v2/identifier?flowName=GlifWebSignIn&flowEntry=ServiceLogin)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to click the button using the id `'ow281'`
See the following code:

```
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome 

chrome = Chrome()

element = chrome.find_element_by_id('ow281')
element.click()
```

I obtained this id by using the Inspect tool in Google Chrome, right clicking the element, and selecting 'Copy selector'

Comment: i get this error `Message: Unable to locate element: /html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div`

Comment: Try this instead: `self.driver.find_element_by_id('ow281').click()`